# Install Ubuntu on HP Pavilion (Vista SP2) dv6397ea

Tags: hp, overheating, windows-vista

I have got a ten-year old HP Pavilion dv6397ea running under Vista SP2, Intel Core2 CPU-t7200 2.00ghz with 2G RAM. My video adapter model is NVidia GEForce GO 7400. I have got many hardware problems such as my computer running ultra-slow, overheating (I have removed my battery ages ago). I have cleaned my laptop a year ago and replaced the cooling gel on the processor.

I'm considering reformatting my hard drive and installing Ubuntu v.12 to reduce usage of my slowly-dying machine. I haven't got much use for games or specialized software (I already use open-source software for most of my daily tasks), Ubuntu seems like a logical choice.

However I have talked to my entourage and they told me that there might a be a **problem installing Ubuntu because my HP might be "tattooed" and some of my hardware might not be recognized under Ubuntu**. I have tried finding documentation on this, it's like searching for a needle inside a haystack... 
Is there any guide available or links on the Ubuntu website that would help me decide? 
Thank you for any help in advance,
Marylene

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add hardware details of the laptop you are asking about.

Comment: hi, I thought I did already.. Would I find all this info under "System information"?

Comment: You will need CPU name, RAM size and video adapter model at least.

Comment: Edited my post to include hardware details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking in account the hardware, I would suggest installing 32-bit version of Ubuntu 14.04 or Xubuntu 14.04. I do not expect any serious hardware problems. If there are any, you are welcome to ask questions.

But before you install, you can boot from installation usb or DVD, choose "Try Ubuntu" and test how everything works.

Comment: Thanks Pilot6, I'm making a bootable usb as we speak and will try it out.

Comment: Clean install of Ubuntu 14.04, no hardware problems, everything works like a breeze, It's like having a brand new computer! Thanks again

Comment: Then mark it as solved.

Comment: By editing my original post and adding "Solved"?

Comment: No by clicking "accepted" at the answer. http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Can't seem to find that option even after reading this article: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnansweredPostsTeam/SolvedThreads

Comment: It looks like you did that already.